# Flutter_animate Package error No named parameter with the name 'enabled'. enabled: sigmaX > minBlur || sigmaY > minBlur,

Tags: flutter, animation, package, pubspec

I created a new flutter project and added the flutter_animate: 3.1.0 package to the pubspec.ymal. Also write basic code just to explore the flutter_animate package. But when i run my project i got the following error.

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animate-3.1.0/lib/src/effects/blur_effect.dart:47:11: Error: No named parameter with the name 'enabled'.
          enabled: sigmaX > minBlur || sigmaY > minBlur,
          ^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/image_filter.dart:26:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const ImageFiltered({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I read the flutter_animate readme and also tried to fix this

Answer (score 0):

It seems the enabled attribute is only available since Flutter 3.3.0

See this issue for more information: https://github.com/gskinner/flutter_animate/issues/41